# my BroadCastRececiver (onReceivr) Not work at all android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered my Receiver in mainfist XML, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <manifest android:versionName="1.0"
  android:versionCode="1"
  package="com.eiq.randomsendriod"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.eiq.randomsendriod.SendRandom"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="myreceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.esmaeel.incomIM">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".seekNet"></service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

declared My **BroadCastReceiver**:

```
public BroadcastReceiver myreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Toast.makeText(context,"I have raceived a        broadcast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("SEMOAS","In onReceive(...)");
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {

                incom.setBody(bundle.get("body").toString());
                incom.setFrom(bundle.get("From").toString());
                incom.setTo(bundle.get("To").toString());
                incom.setTogender(bundle.get("toGender").toString());
                incom.my_gender=bundle.get("SenderGender").toString();
                incom.type=bundle.getInt("msgType");
                incom.url=bundle.get("url").toString();
                incom.userID=bundle.get("SenderID").toString();
Log.e("SEMOA","Message ariived to activity via Brodcasting");
                Toast.makeText(context,"Congratulations!!! got message: "+   incom.getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Log.e("SEMOA","Message ariived to activity via Brodcasting-----null");
        }
    };
```

and Sending broadcast from my Service:

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    Log.e("SEMOA", "IN RUNNABLE");
    try {
    if ((incom = (Message) SendRandom.ObjectInServercht.readUnshared()) == null)
    Log.e("ESMOA","No incumming messages!!!");
    else {

    myI.putExtra("body", incom.getBody());// myI is an intent
    myI.putExtra("From", incom.getFrom());
    myI.putExtra("To", incom.getTo());
    myI.putExtra("toGender", incom.getTogender());
    myI.putExtra("SenderGender", incom.my_gender);
    myI.putExtra("msgType", incom.type);
    myI.putExtra("url", incom.url);
    myI.putExtra("SenderID", incom.userID);

   myI.setAction("com.esmaeel.incomIM");
   try{
   seekNet.this.sendBroadcast(myI);
   Log.e("ESMOA","sendBroadcast!!");
   }catch(Exception e){
   Log.e("ESMOA","not sent sendBroadcast!! "+ e.toString());
   }

   }
```

the send part Success, I see: `Log.e("ESMOA","sendBroadcast!!");` result in logcat, 
but the receive function (onReceive) never run!

In the XML manifest file: `<receiver android:name="myreceiver">`, the value "myreceiver" apeare in red and unresolved!

May you point on the error?

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` to your manifest as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not implementing your receiver correctly. To register the receiver in the manifest, it needs to be a subclass of BroadcastReceiver, and *not* an instance of BroadcastReceiver in the Activity. You need to create a receiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver, like so:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"I have raceived a broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("SEMOAS","In onReceive(...)");
        ...
```

This needs to be in its own file, MyReceiver.java.

Your manifest would need to be changed to:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.esmaeel.incomIM">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If, on the other hand, you only need your receiver to be active while your Activity is running, you would register it in the Activity with the `registerReceiver()` method. In this case, you would remove the `receiver` entry from your manifest, and keep the rest of the Activity code as it is.

Comment: thanks Mike M, I did : created a class and override its onReceive, and register it in the manifest, but still face the same problem!!

Comment: Do you mean MyReceiver is still in red? Or the receiver just isn't getting the broadcast?

Comment: Ohhh , its working now :) After your solution the error was just typo!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Manifest:
add this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and also as you've already done add receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="PACKAGE.AlarmReciever" />
```

now build your AlarmReciever:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = context;
        try {

            // Do whatever you want here

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Then you can call it in your code like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReciever.class);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) MIL-YOU-WANT-TO-WAKE-UP / 1000);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, instance.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
```

Hope it helps :)